# Input field value freeze while typing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selection of input fields that are for inputting colour code values. E.G. " **#FF00FF** "

What I would like to do is when selecting and typing in the field, that the "#" stays there at all times by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for the help.
This seemed troublesome, but it is now working ... in an untidy way :)

So with ideas from above and tweaking, this is what I found to work.

First I changed my input handeler from

> ```
> onblur="changeColour1(), picker_text_hide()"
> ```

to adding to the list

> ```
> onkeyup="changeColour1(), picker_text_hide()"
> ```

What is doing all the work now is the **changeColour1()** function which is this

> ```
> function changeColour1() {    
> var colour = document.forms['edit_theme'].picker_text1.value;
> colour = colour.replace(/[^a-f0-9]/gi, '').toUpperCase();   
> if (colour.substr(0,1) != '#'){         
> colour = '#'+colour;
> document.forms['edit_theme'].picker_text1.value = colour;   
> }
> document.getElementById("me1").style.backgroundColor = colour; 
> }
> ```

So now all I need is a way to streemline the code as I have 7 of these function blocks to cover the 7 input fields. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (assuming you are using `jQuery`):

```
function onValueChange(e){
    var elem = $(e.target);
    if(elem.val().substr(0,1) != '#'){
        elem.val('#'+elem.val());
    }
}
$('input').on('keyup', onValueChange);
```

### See a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/tX5CM/).

### Bonus: [Extended Version in pure `JavaScript`](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/tX5CM/3/)

Edit: I replaced `e.originalTarget` with `e.target` to make it run outside of `Firefox`

Comment: This seems to be the answer ..... but for some reason my page will not run it. I have a few mixed js to do different things, so might have a conflict. I stuck my page into jsFiddle and it then did work .... but my others did not. ??? Perhaps not loading jQuery ?

Comment: As long as you don't got another `onValueChange` funktion, it sould work. Maybe you are missing jQuery? What does `console.log($)` return to you?

Comment: I created an extended, jquery free example for you :)

Comment: I have "
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> " in HEAD ... I have an "onblur" in the text field that runs 2 scripts. And my knowlage of jQyery is no-existant, just what I can find and use. :p

Comment: Downvoted since backspacing the # moves the caret from the start of the line to the end.

Comment: Since you are not using jQuery for your whole project, I recommend trying to use the second snippet - which doens't depend on jQuery.

Comment: Can you illustrate this, Douglas? If I delete the `#` Firefox just inserts it again at the start

Comment: Just tested your js fiddle on line and only seems to work in FF , and trying it on my page brakes some of my other code.

Comment: Here is my page so far. will be here for the duration of testing. http://www.myonlinelocation.com/colour_test/   NO jQuery in it

Comment: My bad, I wrote `e.originalTarget` instead of `e.target`. Does this fix the problem for you? (I updated the fiddle above)

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus - Works in the "fiddle" now as you have it, but still no go on my page .... No idea why, but thanks anyway. I have updated my post below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the # outside the inputfield and use some css to make it look like it was inside:

```
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:20; left:10px">#</div>
<input type="text" value="" style="padding-left:20px;"/>
```

add some more font styling to make it the same size. then when reading the value with
javascript just add the #

Comment: Nice idea, but in case the user wants to select & copy the (whole) value, this might cause problems

Comment: yes thats right, I was just thinking of using it programmatically.

Comment: I like the idea, but as @RienNeVaPlus said, not going to work for my needs.